# Handlebars.js: how to get object key from the template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
Handlebars.compile({{FOO bar}})({ bar: "baz" });

--> 

bar: baz
```

In my [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com) helper `FOO` I need to access the key that was used to access the object. How do I do that? I need this for debugging, so the solution does not have to be very clean or efficient.

Here is a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/eygs74yL/

Comment: That's not possible. Pass the name as an additional parameter.

Comment: It is: http://jsfiddle.net/pdq51gra/. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: BTW, I'm especially interested in getting the key for `undefined` values. And *that* is probably not possible without patching Handlebars.js. I wonder what would be the best way to patch it...

Comment: @MauricePerry It is possible, after all. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to set `trackIds` flag when compiling the template.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("FOO", function(arg, options) {
    return options.ids[0] + ": " + arg;
});

$("div").html(
  Handlebars.compile("{{FOO bar}}", { trackIds:true }
)({ bar: "baz" }));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eygs74yL/1/

Comment: That's smart. That trackIds options looks handy.